# still Invalid Api-key cause facebook login error?

Tags: android

I created facebook application and i put key in key hash 
still facebook login failed
error is Invalid key error.
Plz help me.
my application is ready but this problem cause delay in publishing my application.

the steps that i followed to get key hash are

1. copied all file from OpenSSl into jdk
2. set path to C:/programfiles/java/jdk/bin in command prompt
3. then run= keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "[PATH]\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
4. got hash key +ZRWQIs5LsdDsBNdoJ8wT2RyYrE=
5. copied into native android app in hash key but still error occurred plz help me

Comment: step 3 should ask you for password. If its not asking for password you are doing something wrong.

Comment: there could be the problem with path you've provided for the debug.keystore. Using command prompt navigate to the folder where you have the debug.keystore. Now Type edit command, after that close the dos editor you'll notice that the path is shortened by the DOS. Copy this path with the debug.keystore and use it in command of Step 3. This should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks but tell me that i used eclipse and to install application on mobile device i export signed application package and that time i created new keystore in another folder.so plz tell me that which keystore path i have to used,the newly created or provided in .android folder and same for alias name.Plz tell me?

Comment: you should use whatever keystore that you are using to sign your apk. Which means if you using bot development purpose use debug.keystore. or else use your production keystroe.

Comment: thanks and sorry for asking same questions but i tried out both keystore but it given error every time.Error means on device application felled to connect to facebook.thats why i am asking same type of question.will you plz tell me all steps one more time.Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to generate your keyhash.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore [your path]/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

use "android" as a password.
For more information on facebook Single Sign-On you can check the [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso)